# Why the compiler ignores the command \noindent?

Tags: spacing

I am writing my master thesis on LaTeX. I should say that I had not used it before and everything is new for me. I was doing fine until I got some troubles when compiling the command \noindent and \hline.

I want my title page to end with an horizontal line at the bottom and the place where I am working and the date right above it. There is a very nice blank space from the supervisor's name to the bottom margin which the compiler just ignores and places the name of the city and the line in the next page. The frame of the page tells me that there is still space for placing text. Needless to say, I loaded the geometry with [showframe].

Moreover, I get an error message because of \hline which says >misplaced \noalign.

I had to modify the location of the vertical margin as well as the height of the body's box. Might that be the reason why the last line jumps into the next page?

```
%--------Code in the main.tex file, prior to any page-----------%
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}   %loads the graphics package, necessary for pictures
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}   %allows to change margins and distances within the page's frame
%\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{framed}     %to make frames, such as in the title page and abstract
\usepackage{hyperref}
\graphicspath{{images/}}    %Direction where LaTeX will look for the images.
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

%-----------Here the Title Page starts, in a different .tex file-----------%

\begin{titlepage}

%% COMMANDS DEFINED FOR THE USER
\newcommand\textline[4][t]{%
\par\smallskip\noindent\parbox[#1]{.333\textwidth}{\large\raggedright\texttt{}#2}%
\parbox[#1]{.333\textwidth}{\large\centering\textbf{#3}}%
\parbox[#1]{.333\textwidth}{\raggedleft\texttt{#4}}\par\smallskip%
}

\newcommand\specialtxtl[4][t]{%
\par\smallskip\noindent\parbox[#1]{.2\textwidth}{\large\raggedright\texttt{}#2}%
\parbox[#1]{.6\textwidth}{\LARGE\centering\textbf{#3}}%
\parbox[#1]{.2\textwidth}{\raggedleft\texttt{#4}}\par\smallskip%
}
%------------------------------------------------%

\setlength{\voffset}{-2.5cm} %---This commands here are for changing the margin of the page, so the image can be placed up there. They must be before \begin{center} otherwise they don't work.

\setlength{\textheight}{690pt}  %height of the box where the text is placed.

\begin{center}

    \begin{figure}[h]
        \hspace*{-3.0cm}
        %\includegraphics{title_header}
    \end{figure}

    \vspace{0.0cm}

    \LARGE
    \begin{framed}      %----Frame around the tile-----
        \vspace{1cm}
        \textbf{Experimental Characterization of Steady-State Applied Field Magnetoplasmadynamic Thruster SX3}
        \vspace{1cm}
    \end{framed}

    \LARGE
    \vspace{.5cm}
    \textbf{Master Thesis}

    %------------------------------------------------%

   \vspace{.5cm}
   \textline[t]{Submitted by:}{\LARGE My Name}{}

   \textline[t]{Matriculation Number:}{\LARGE 123456789}{}

   \vspace{.5cm}

   \specialtxtl[t]{at:}{Master's program}{}

   \textbf{"Aerospace Engineering"}

   \vspace{1.0cm}
   \specialtxtl[t]{Supervisor:}{Name Name}{}
   \textbf{\LARGE Name Name}

   \vspace{\fill}
   \LARGE
   \raggedright Stuttgart, 19/03/2015
   \rule{\textwidt}{.5pt}

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

%-------------------------------------------------------------%

\chapter*{Abstract}  %--From here is just the template of the thesis, table of content and chapters.
Standard standard standard standard standard standard standard standard standard

\chapter{Aknowledgement}
I want to thank...

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
Standard Standard standard standard standard standard

\end{document}
```

I would appreciate so much some help. Thank you.

Voyager

Comment: \hline is only used inside a tabular.  Use \rule{\textwidth}{.5pt} instead.

Comment: I doubt you want to use `figure`. `figure` is a float. It tells LaTeX to move the contents to the 'best position' according to its algorithm. Unless you want your title graphic to be moved elsewhere if LaTeX thinks best, you don't want to make it a float.

Comment: `\noindent` does not take an argument `\noindent{Stuttgart, 19/03/2015}` is same as `\noindent Stuttgart, 19/03/2015` and it is not ignored but the effect is not visible as paragraph indentation is set to 0pt in a `center` environment.

Comment: `\texttt{}` selects monospace font but then always typesets nothing in that font. What was the intention there?

Comment: First of all, thank you all for your time answering me.  @cfr I just added the code in the main file, as you asked me, so you got all the code I used here. I used `figure` because I wanted the image (logo and header of the university) to be in the top of the page. That's why I used `\voffset{-2.5cm}`. Do you know another way to do it without messing up the page layout? That would be helpfull.  @john Thanks for your command, it works.  @david thanks for the reply. About `texttt{}` my friend helped me out with this page. He gave me this line of code, and I just copied it. Works fine without it

Comment: @Voyager Please make it so we can copy-paste-compile to reproduce the issue. That code will certainly not compile. As for the logo, just don't use `figure`. But really, you will save time and frustration if you stop and read up on the basics.

Comment: @cfr I'll try to solve it using a different command. As you and others said, that might be the problem which screws up the layout. Anyway, my title page is in a different .tex file than the main, so the `input` command will not work for you unless you create the files as I did.

Comment: Well, the `center` environment adds vertical space before and after its contents. Is that what you mean? Use `\centering` if you don't want the space.

Comment: To be honest, I'm rather losing track of what you are trying to do here. Why did you want to change `voffset` and `textheight` for the first page? (And why doesn't `geometry` get told about it?)

Comment: @cfr I just checked and compile your code. That is the layout I wanted to make for my master thesis, only for the title page. The reason why I used `hspace{-3.0cm}` is that my university logo is too wide for the page. If I let LaTeX place it where it thinks is the best, the logo is not centered. I cannot change the logo image, it's what I was given. And the reason why I applied the `voffset` was for placing the image close to the upper border of the page. I did not manage to apply a header. But really, your code is helpful. I just have to place the logo instead of the black box. Thanks.

Comment: `\makebox[0pt]{\includegraphics{logo}}` within the scope of a centring command will centre the image without having to calculate the appropriate horizontal adjustment. As for `voffset`: you are using `geometry`. So don't set the page layout dimensions directly else there is no point in loading the package. It can't help adjust the layout by calculating things for you if you go around making changes to the layout on the sly. In order to do its job, ***it needs to know about any change to the page layout dimensions***.

Comment: @Voyager The `0pt` box is kind of a neat trick. Though I probably only think this because I only learnt it recently ;).

Comment: @cfr I finally got the layout I wanted for my thesis. Thanks a lot. And the command `\makebox[0pt]` does not show the warning message for overflow because of the logo image. Thanks a lot for your help and excuse me for the obvious and avoidable mistakes. See you around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is cleaned up a very little. Note that I really have no idea what you are trying to do so I doubt very much that my answer will help you do it!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{framed}

\newcommand\textline[4][t]{%
  \par\smallskip\noindent\parbox[#1]{.333\textwidth}{\large\raggedright\texttt{}#2}%
  \parbox[#1]{.333\textwidth}{\large\centering\textbf{#3}}%
  \parbox[#1]{.333\textwidth}{\raggedleft\texttt{#4}}\par\smallskip%
}

\newcommand\specialtxtl[4][t]{%
  \par\smallskip\noindent\parbox[#1]{.2\textwidth}{\large\raggedright\texttt{}#2}%
  \parbox[#1]{.6\textwidth}{\LARGE\centering\textbf{#3}}%
  \parbox[#1]{.2\textwidth}{\raggedleft\texttt{#4}}\par\smallskip%
}

\begin{document}
  \newgeometry{headheight=0pt,textheight=690pt}% doubt your really want voffset=-25mm as it pushes the content off the page
  \begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    \hspace*{-3.0cm}
    \includegraphics{title_header}

      \LARGE
      \begin{framed}
        \vspace{1cm}
        \textbf{Experimental Characterization of Steady-State Applied Field Magnetoplasmadynamic Thruster SX3}
        \vspace{1cm}
      \end{framed}

      \LARGE
      \vspace{.5cm}
      \textbf{Master Thesis}

      \vspace{.5cm}
      \textline[t]{Submitted by:}{\LARGE My Name}{}

      \textline[t]{Matriculation Number:}{\LARGE 123456789}{}

      \vspace{.5cm}

      \specialtxtl[t]{at:}{Master's program}{}

      \textbf{``Aerospace Engineering''}

      \vspace{1.0cm}
      \specialtxtl[t]{Supervisor:}{Name Name}{}
      \textbf{\LARGE Name Name}

      \vspace{\fill}
      \LARGE
      \raggedright Stuttgart, 19/03/2015
      \rule{\textwidth}{.5pt}
  \end{titlepage}
  \restoregeometry

  \chapter*{Abstract}
  Standard standard standard standard standard standard standard standard standard

  \chapter{Aknowledgement}
  I want to thank...

  \tableofcontents

  \chapter{Introduction}
  Standard Standard standard standard standard standard

\end{document}
```

[image: page layouts]